# Unable to push to BitBucket - an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: tortoisehg, bitbucket

I am trying to push my changes to my Bitbucket's private repository.

The push process starts initially, like as shown in the screenshot below...

[image]

but after some time I get the following message :

[image]

The error message reads :

> URLError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I am trying this for quite a time now... I was able to send 19000+/24076KB, is what I remember.

I am new to Tortoise HG and these kind of errors always prevent me to migrate from SVN to either GIT/HG :`(

Comment: Seems like a question for Bitbucket support?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for bitbucket support. It's not something that could be resolved here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only bitbucket can solve this (though I just ran into it too ;) )